# Intercept and redirect request in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, spring-rest

We have configure base path in our apis to have `"/api"` by using `server.servlet-path=/api` in application.properties and now the swagger documentation is available at `http://host:port/api/swagger-ui.html`

But as all our services docmentation is available at `http://host:8080/swagger-ui.html`, we want this service also serve at the same path.

Now I want to intercept api call to `http://host:8080/swagger-ui.html` and redirect it to `http://host:8080/api/swagger-ui.html`.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/")
public class SwaggerRedirectController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/swagger-ui.html")
    public void redirectToTwitter(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws IOException {
        httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("https://host/api/swagger-ui.html");
```

As we already set the base path to "/api", though request is coming to /swagger-ui.html, it is appended with "/api" as base path and not hitting this custom api.

I want to intercept this request and remove `"/api"` from it so that it will hit this custom api which eventually redirected `/api/swagger-ui.html`

Is this possible? or any other ways to do it

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can redirect specific requests to another path using `Interceptor`

Here is an example that shows how you can do it:

```java
@Component
public class CustomInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest requestServlet, HttpServletResponse responseServlet, Object handler) throws Exception {
        if (requestServlet.getRequestURI().equals("/swagger-ui.html")){
            responseServlet.sendRedirect("/api/swagger-ui.html");
            logger.info("redirect request for url: {} to: /api/swagger-ui.html", requestServlet.getRequestURI());
            return false;

        }
        return super.preHandle(requestServlet, responseServlet, handler);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

I forgot to add config class to activate interceptor. My bad, I'm sorry. Here is configuration class to activate this interceptor:

```java
@Configuration
public class Config implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    CustomInterceptor customInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(customInterceptor);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is still not going to the intercetpor. It is hitting `Request URL: http://localhost:8080/swagger-resources/configuration/ui` and other swagger resource and failing with 404 as they not available at the URL as `/api` has been added as the base path

Comment: I added log inside interceptor as first statement and never printed so it is not hitting intercetpor

Comment: I have just realized that I forgot to add config class, and edited answer. Sorry for late response. @arjun